# Android doesnt recognize image with text in button?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-button

I have tried to add a small icon to android text button .I am getting below errors, even though i have manually added one phone.png image in drawable folder.

But some how when i add "drawable/ic_launcher_search" it does shows a small search icon ,even though i couldnt find in my drawable folder with such name. may be i am missing something how to add and may be it support some other file format in other folders. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@drawable/pressedcolor"
        android:id="@+id/calculate_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_launcher_search"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_normal"
        android:text="aaaaaaCalcula
```

te">

Comment: Which image is in drawable which you want to add?

Comment: how can i ass custom image , does that image support png or it has some method of adding custom image

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean the project and Run again

Comment: can i add any image inside drawable folder as png and use them .. do u mean i have to add "  drawableLeft="drawable/phone" instead of "android:drawableLeft="drawable/phone"
"

Comment: AAPT: error: resource android:drawable/nonet not found.

Comment: actually nonet is an nonet.png image inside drawable folder

Comment: clean the project and run again

Comment: after cleaning project it worked and thanks for the help